# How to get the value from an array in ionic?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a php file.
Response from php-

```
response:"{"status":true,"originalName":"1527931554722.png","generatedName":"ceabe4c3b0074eb3d64cca21493be324.png"}"
```

I want to get the value of generatedName in ionic. 
I used this code:->

`let name = response[3]; console.log(name);`

It gives output 't' on console.

Comment: @krandeep please mark as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response:"{"status":true,"originalName":"1527931554722.png","generatedName":"ceabe4c3b0074eb3d64cca21493be324.png"}"
```

try response.generatedName

Answer (score 2):

You do not need index here, just access the **`property`** since its already an **`object`**.

**DEMO**

```js
let response = {"status":true,"originalName":"1527931554722.png","generatedName":"ceabe4c3b0074eb3d64cca21493be324.png"};

console.log(response.generatedName);
```